# Where I can find maven2 repository with jsf 2.0.3?

Tags: maven-2, maven, jsf-2

Where I can find maven2 repository with jsf 2.0.3? I've searched in Google and saw one of developers say that it is on download.java.net, but my Maven doesn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the corresponding artifacts in this repository :

http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/faces/

([add this repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) in your `settings.xml` file)

and then use the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer and see another repo that I've find while waiting for answer

Answer (score 0):

It's in java.net.  Try

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

(edited)

Comment: This is not the dependency he is looking for!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answer that I get, there are jsf-impl and jsf-api with version 2.0.3 in [https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss][1] repo. the dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hey, I didn't find this version on this repository. Is it removed or what?